# Connecting Old Tandy monitor to new computer

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I've got this old Tandy 1000 monitor lying around, and just for fun, I'd like to try to connect this to one of my laptops. The problem is, the monitor is so old, he connector is a 9 pin VGA, while my laptop's out is HDMI. While I am aware you can buy converters for each of these, will it work? If not, are there any emulators or graphics settings that I could change to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: First of all it is *not VGA*. VGA is *15* pin analog interface.
Tandy used TGA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandy_Graphics_Adapter) which is based on CGA.
CGA was *9 pin* *digital* interface *incompatible* with VGA.

I am believe it is impossible to connect TGA monitor to modern hardware, sorry

Comment: Look at this guy.  http://www.ebay.com/itm/Tandy-TRS-80-Micro-Computer-Color-Graphics-Printer-Interface-Card-Adapter-/182640728834?hash=item2a863c5b02:g:s6EAAOSwVm5ZAOPS  Looks to be ISA 8 bit.  Although that doesn't mean it would work on todays modern OSs even if you had an ISA slot.  It has a 9 pin VGA-looking out that might be what @user996142 is mentioning and seems to be a dual purpose for a printer as well.  Now that is multi tasking!

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to conversions, the age of the product(s) is not a factor. **So yes, VGA to HDMI will work with a converter.** I used to use a VGA to HDMI converter about a year ago before I bought the monitor I use today and it worked fine. Just note that the Hertz of the monitor (i.e. 144hz/60hz) will be limited the the output cable (the cable going into the PC). But seeing as you said it's an old monitor, this shouldn't be a problem :)